# Artifactory: Auto-generate archetype catalog?

Tags: java, maven-2, artifactory, archetypes

Is there a way to have Artifactory automatically generate the `archetype-catalog.xml` file for a repository? At the moment, I maintain it by hand and publish it via HTTP PUT. While this is doable for our small internal repository, it would be nice to do this automatically, and I was rather surprised it doesn't seem to happen out of the box.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Can you share how you generate your `archetype-catalog.xml`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edited according to the comment**

What version of artifactory are you using? According to this [issue](http://issues.jfrog.org/jira/browse/RTFACT-651), in version 1.3 it is done using HTTP PUT, while in 2.0 it takes the catalog form the proxied repositories.

I'd suggest you open a ticket for artifactory at http://issues.jfrog.org/jira/browse/RTFACT - it's an open source project after all...

Comment: I'm on the latest version, 2.0.6. I'm afraid the issue only says that Artifactory mirrors the archetype-catalog.xml from one of the repositories it is proxying. I see that behaviour too.

Answer (score 0):

[JFrog](https://www.jfrog.com/jira/browse/RTFACT-651?jql=text%20~%20%22archetype-catalog.xml%22) will not fix under the current road map (07/2014) the behavior described by @Henning because this issue can be developed as a user plugin or maven plugin.

There is an example of a plugin there :
https://github.com/dm-conti/maven-archetype-catalog-plugin